# iPhone programming - Background saving with core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios4

I am trying to save data into core data in the background thread, as it takes quite some time to save.

I did:

```
[self performSelectorInBackGround:@selector(insertRecord:) withObject:data];
```

When all works fine until the line in `insertRecord` Method hits `contextsave:&error`. Program received signal : `"SIGABRT"`

Am I doing anything wrong? it works ok when its in main thread, I just move the codes to another method and run it in background and it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the "Concurrency with Core Data" section of *Core Data Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1):

> The pattern recommended for concurrent programming with Core Data is
>   thread confinement: each thread must have its own entirely private
>   managed object context.

and

> Using thread confinement, you should not pass managed objects or
>   managed object contexts between threads.

It looks like you're passing a managed object to the background thread, which is forbidden. I don't know if you're also trying to share your managed object context between threads.

That document describes a couple of workarounds for passing managed objects to other threads.  You'll need to implement one of them.

Comment: i declared the managed object context in the method, it should create a managed object context on every thread.

Comment: my NSpersistentStoreCoordinator, managedObjectModel etc is declared in the appDelegate. Is that causing the problem?

Comment: You are doing `[self performSelectorInBackGround:@selector(insertRecord:) withObject:data];`.  If `data` is a managed object, that is your problem.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that managed object contexts aren't thread-safe. If your `-insertRecord:` method uses the main thread's managed object context, you're asking for trouble.

The blog [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com) has an article, [Core Data and Threads, Without the Headache](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/) on this very topic and suggests some strategies for saving in the background. The basic idea is to make changes on a context that belongs to a background thread, and then merge the changes into the main thread's context. That gives you an up-to-date context that you can save in the background while still keeping the main thread's context current.

Comment: No i didn't. inside the insertRecord method, i declared a new manageObjectcontext. but the reference is from the app delegate. will that be a problem as well?

Comment: What reference is from the app delegate?

Comment: i declared the NSmanagedObjectModel,NSpersistentStoreCoordinator in the app delegate.

i call the NSmanageObjectContext in the method like this:
ApplicaionAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ApplicationAppDelegate * ) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

Comment: You're just declaring a new pointer, but making it point to the app delegate's context, which was no doubt created on the main thread. This is exactly your problem -- it's not safe to share a single context across threads. You can't just get a reference to the app delegate's context in your background thread; you have to actually create a new context. Of course, that new context will differ from the main thread's context, which presents a problem. And that's the subject of the article that I linked above. Please read it if you plan to save in the background.